# how to render a twig from custom location?

Tags: symfony

i am trying to generate pdf using TCPDF and want to attach this PDF to an email, 
and send it to various email addresses.
What is the right way to render twig file in Services?

Comment: Welcome to SO ! What have you tried so far? Please always include that info!

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this post, was helpful for me:

http://richsage.co.uk/2011/12/16/rendering-emails-with-twig-in-symfony2/

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to add templating to your service

```
your_bundle.your_service_name:
    class: your_project\your_bundle\Service\your_service
    arguments: [@templating]
```

Then you need to add the templating service to your service constructor

```
private $templating;

function __construct($templating)
{
    $this->templating = $templating;
}
```

After that you just need to call it in the function that handle the TCPDF rendering

```
function renderTCPDF()
{
    $renderedTemplate = $this->templating->render('your_bundle:template_folder:twig_name',   array(your_parameters));
}
```